# Dyanamic/ Variable Filepath Python

Tags: python

I'm looking for a method of setting a variable in a path but I can't seem to find some way of doing this:

```
object = apps.[variable].main.run()
```

where `variable` is some string. Apps and Variable are two directories and main is a python script.

(For import statements I was able to use `__import__(path)`)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question. Are you maybe looking for `object = getattr(apps, variable).main.run()`?

Comment: @LukasGraf That looks like what I was searching for, thanks! :)

Comment: @mescalinum Not that new to SO or SE, I'm a moderator over at Aviation ;) I did indeed forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getattr`:

```
getattr(apps, variable).main.run()
```